# How do i make it say: "Write will create (random number goes here) random numbers

Tags: python

How do i make it say: "Write will create (random number goes here) random numbers

```
def main():

    # Open a file for writing
    outfile = open ('mynumbers.txt' , 'w')

    # Generate random integer number
    from random import randint
    print(randint(0,9))

main()
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: The code i have now generates the random number. I just need it to say "Write will create (random number goes here) random numbers" where i put "random number goes here" is where the generated number should go. if you catch my drift

Comment: What lines of research did you try? Did you look into string formatting? Did you look into string concatenation? Have you followed any basic Python tutorials yet?

Comment: welll im using this python book but ehh its cofusing to me

Comment: @PhillipEllis Get used to being confused. It's a daily occurrence in programming. You are going to have to learn the art of taking what you know and either using it to learn more or combining it to make something more complex. When you get confused and what you already know just isn't cutting it, then you have to start doing research. What Google searches did you try? What resources did you read and try to use?

Comment: I bet, im just trying to take it in piece by piece becasue it is depressing. I did look on google and i seen things related to it but not the exact function i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the following?

```
from random import randint

number = randint(0, 9)
print("Write will create", number, "random numbers")
```

Or

```
from random import randint

number = randint(0, 9)
print("Write will create %d random numbers" % number)
```

?

Comment: The code i have now generates the randowm number. I just need it to say "Write will create (random number goes here) random numbers"  where i put "random number goes here" is where the generated number should go. if you catch my drift

Comment: Did you import `randint` from `random` ?

Comment: Honestly have no clue what that means.

Comment: honestly, better find some tutorial. I changed code in my answer.

Comment: @PhillipEllis If you don't know what an `import` is, you don't have the basics of Python down. I agree with furas: you need to get some very low level basics down before you continue. A tutorial is a good way to do that. I've been told good things about this book: [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/) (available online in full for free).

Comment: Thank you. You answered my question. Sorry about the noob questions, this book isnt very descriptive so im kinda lost at some points to fend for myself  @furas